# Enabling use of wildcard in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I already have a stored proc that will find any column defining by the user, but now I would like to expand it to include wildcards( in case the user only knows part of the column name. How do I give my stored proc this ability?

Comment: I hope you're taking appropriate precautions to prevent [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Allowing users to directly specify fields is a scary idea - hopefully you don't have any tables where some fields don't need to be private at all times, e.g. password hash fields.

Comment: Showing your procedure would probably be a good start.

Comment: yes. code f you still need help.. without knowing what you are doing its hard to help.. other then to say that oracle has 2 "wildcard" type options.. `LIKE` and `REGEXP_LIKE`